# Distinct Path between 2 chars in Mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a column "path" - a valid path looks like:
`"PAGE:StackOverflow:SystemOfReptation:HowTo"`
or
`"COOKBOOK:Awesome:Cookie"`

I need to Distinct all Names in the first Section.
So i have a List like:

```
Sections:  
1. PAGE  
2. COOKBOOK
```

And i need to Distinct all Names in the second Section of a spiecial first Section.
Like for the "PAGE" first Section:

```
Section of "PAGE"

1 .StackOverflow
```

I have absolutely no idea how i can do this is there something like Regex in Mysql i can use for this?

Thanks for Your Help

Comment: Normally, operations on the results will lead to full table scans or temporary/filesort. Are you 100% sure that this is the only way you can have the "Path" value?

Comment: @senape there is another possibility but this results in much much more time for development.

Its much more effective to solve this feature with this setup.
This data can be Cached really good in my case.

Comment: ok. do you need the two results (a list with the sections AND a list with the sub-section grouped by section) or it has to be just the distinct list of subsections?

Comment: I need only the distinct list of the first section.
And on a seperate query a distinct list of the subsection of one of the first sections - like a distinct list off all subsections of "PAGE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the distinct list of the first section, you can use the MySQL functions 
[substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PATH, ':', 1)) SECTIONS
FROM MY_TABLE
```

This will return the distinct list of everything behind the ":". Please note that if the PATH has no ":", it will be returned entirely. 
If you need, you can add a where clause such as:

```
WHERE INSTR(PATH, ":") <> 0
```

instr() function will return the position of the first occurrence.

Finally, you can use the above query as a subquery to be joined on the same table to extract the second level of your path.

Comment: Thank You for your Answer!
i can use your 1 Code like it is.

For the Second i have made This:

`SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PATH, ':', 2)) path FROM items WHERE path LIKE "PAGE:%"`

Comment: if you don't need to split the subpath, i.e. you are ok with PAGE:whatever, you could make something a bit more elegant, such as `SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PATH, ':', 2)) path, SUBSTRING_INDEX(PATH, ':',1) sections FROM items HAVING sections = "PAGE"`